# One tap printing on iPhone

Tags: iphone, printing, bonjour, airprint

I want to make an app on the iPhone that would print an image just by tapping a button. I've tried the tutorials about UIPrintInteractionController  online, but all of them will take me to a selection page before I can actually print. Can I programmatically skip that page by sending a default print job directly to an available printer that the iOS can connect to?

Answer (score 1):

No.  Using the printing UI is a requirement; otherwise, the user doesn't have a way to change printers or set printer settings.  Unlike a desktop computer, printers in iOS are transient, so there's not a notion of a "default printer" or configuration for one-click printing.

See [the Drawing and Printing guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/Printing/Printing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH12-SW7) for more information about the UI expectations for apps which print.

Comment: This is unfortunate, for apps in controlled environments the extra step of always choosing the same printer is annoying.

Comment: The app could just pick a default printer. Also, audio devices are transient and defaults are used there is no reason for this to be different for printers. You dont get asked what audio device to use every time a an app plays a sound.